# Почему не работает валидация формы?

Tags: javascript, html, form

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, почему валидация моей формы [не работает](http://prozaik.16mb.com/valid/), а принципиально идентичный код на официальном сайте скрипта [работает](http://itforms.ru/)?

Comment: автор, извините ,вы издеваетесь что ли? Или вы предлагаете лезть отладчиком и ковырять ваш JavaScript и всю ту порнографию, что там есть? (кстати, я все-таки залез, и увидел там какой-то ад с кодировкой. Вполне может быть, что проблемы в этом) Без обид, автор, но если вы просите помощи, то тогда  постарайтесь помочь тем, кто хотел бы помочь вам

Comment: спасибо и за это. а в каком файле вы нашли непонятную кодировку?

Comment: в файлах itform.class.js и itforms.class.js 
например вот это: 
closeText: 'Çàêðûòü',
prevText: '&#x3c;Ïðåä', 
и в таком же духе весь код в файлах

Answer (score 4):

Как минимум не увидел на вашей страничке инициализацию валидации. Вы подключили скрипт валидации на страницу. Добавили форму. Но где же Инициализация скрипта с указанием нужной формы?  К  чему он должен был применяться? Смотрим в сорц на оф.сайте и видим там такие строки

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var itform = new ITForm($('#form1')); //вот привязка к форме
    itform.setCheckboxProperty('check2', 'csv', 2, 4); //checkboxname, sendAs, minSelected, maxSelected
    itform.setCheckboxProperty('check3', 'sum', 1, 2);
//и т.д. дальше идет настройка валидации. 
});
```

Смотрите и разбирайтесь в этом направлении.

Comment: спасибо всем. проблема решена

Comment: @Sergey: тогда не забудьте принять ответ